# Mercurial: Checkout Files for Revision

Tags: mercurial, vcs-checkout, revisions

Is it possible to checkout all the files in a repository for a specific revision?  Say for example that my repository is at revision 88.  I don't want to revert or backout any of the changes up to revision 88, but just get a copy of them at revision 50.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To update your working directory to revision `<rev>`:

```
hg update -r <rev>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to David Levesqe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412253) you could use [`hg clone`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#clone) with the `--updaterev` (or `-u`) option to make a copy with a specific revision, for example:

```
hg clone --updaterev 50 yourRepo/ copyWithRev50/
```